# PDFBox Layout: Add Line Break to StyledText

Tags: layout, pdfbox, line-breaks, styledtext

I'm using [pdfbox-layout](https://github.com/ralfstuckert/pdfbox-layout) and I want to add line breaks to a StyledText Element but can't manage to do it.

If a styled text contains a line break "\n", I get the following error message:

> "StyledText must not contain line breaks, use TextFragment.LINEBREAK for that"

But I can't find an example in the documentation that shows how use `TextFragment.LINEBREAK`.

Does anybody have an example or a alternative solution for this?

**SOLUTION:**

I found a solution how to do it. You need to create a NewLine Textfragment and add it to the TextFlow every time you need a linebreak. Here is an example:

```
NewLine linebreak = new NewLine(fontSize);
TextFlow textflow = new TextFlow();
textflow.add("first line");
textflow.add(linebreak);
textflow.add("second line");
textflow.add(linebreak);
textflow.add("third line");
textflow.drawText(contentStream, posX, posY, Alignment.Left, drawListener);
```

Comment: It's PDFBox respectively an extension of it -> https://github.com/ralfstuckert/pdfbox-layout

Comment: I made clearer that you are looking for a solution in the context of that add-on to PDFBox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution how to do it. You need to create a NewLine Textfragment and add it to the TextFlow every time you need a linebreak. Here is an example:

```
NewLine linebreak = new NewLine(fontSize);
TextFlow textflow = new TextFlow();
textflow.add("first line");
textflow.add(linebreak);
textflow.add("second line");
textflow.add(linebreak);
textflow.add("third line");
textflow.drawText(contentStream, posX, posY, Alignment.Left, drawListener);
```